Java NIO server-client - Connection refused
This is the Client class method that connects to the server. Server runs in its own thread, clients connect in the main thread. Here is the connect method:
 public void connect()
{
        try {
            this.socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

I get java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, from the SocketChannel.open method, because the server is not ready yet and first client is already connecting. If I do Thread.sleep() after the server starts, then it works. How to do it in some more elegant way to not use Thread.sleep(). Is it possible to somehow use the Socket isConnected() method here?

No. Just sleep.

You probably want to sleep and retry in a loop for some number of retries, then throw an exception if the maximum number of retries is exceeded

It's normal to try a connection and if it fails, wait (i.e. sleep) a little while and then try again. You don't want to spam connection attempts, so even just waiting for something around 400ms (which is less than half a second) will hardly make any difference in performance.
Also decide on how long you should wait until you give up. If you decide that you should stop trying to connect if it doesn't happen in 5 seconds, then you can loop this 5000/400 = 12 times. If you want to wait 9 seconds and attempt every 600ms, then you can loop it 9000/600 = 15 times.

This is a common socket issue, you need to wait for the SO to provision the listen port for the process.
For example if you do two entry points (i.e. to main classes), one for server, another for client, it will work just fine because the time between the start of the two processes is enough time.
But when sharing the same process (for example, a test case) you will need to make use of a small sleep.
You can see samples of this behavior here and here.
